# How to add where condition in query if one variables is not null

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT CodicePrenotazione, CodicePersonaFisica, Nome, Cognome,
       Data, NomeFile, PathFile
FROM AA_V_H_Referti H
  INNER JOIN AA_V_ANAG_PersoneFisiche PF
    ON H.CodicePersonaFisica = PF.CodiceFiscale
WHERE PF.CodicePersonale = @CodicePersonale
  AND Data >= @DataInizio
  AND Data <= @DataFine
```

This query works, but now I want to add another where clause but only if one variables is not null.
So I have this variables:

```
DECLARE @TipologiaReferto NVARCHAR(500)

......code to populate this variables
```

now if this variables is not null I want to add this condition on the query

```
AND TipologiaReferto LIKE @TipologiaReferto
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
AND (TipologiaReferto LIKE @TipologiaReferto OR @TipologiaReferto IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
AND (TipologiaReferto LIKE @TipologiaReferto AND @TipologiaReferto != NULL)
```

if this does not trigger the required result as it also will not return any data set for TigoloigaReferto = NULL, then you might want to put the condition inside the JOIN statement.

Not sure if this works, but how about:

```
LEFT JOIN @TipologiaReferto AS TR
ON H.Data = TR.TipologiaReferto
```